# Add a generic (not bound to a key nor field) error message to rails FormObject

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following ruby class:

```
class MyFormObject < FormObject
  attribute :some_field

  validates :some_field, presence: true
  validate :my_custom_validation

  def my_custom_validation
    errors.add "Do_not_have_key","This error message is self contained, not linked to any field and no field prefix required"
  end
end
```

I would like to perform my custom validation logic. Add errors to the error collection, but **some** of them are not bound to any key or field. Let's say they depend on the position of the moon at the moment the validation is performed :)

Also I would like when someone else is using my class and calls:

```
errors.full_messages
```

To get the default behaviour of appending key of the error in front of all the errors, expect the "generic"/ "not bound to a field" ones.

Is there elegant way to achieve such behaviour? And close the solution/workaround whatever in this class and all of the consumers are unaware that there are "special" errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the Rails docs here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#errors-base

> You can add error messages that are related to the object's state as a
>   whole, instead of being related to a specific attribute. You can use
>   this method when you want to say that the object is invalid, no matter
>   the values of its attributes. Since errors[:base] is an array, you can
>   simply add a string to it and it will be used as an error message.

So in your case your validator becomes:

```
def my_custom_validation
  errors[:base] << "Your error message here."
end
```

Comment: Excellent. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much! How could I miss this :)

Comment: Haha, happens to the best of us.